# Perform grep on individual results of a command spawned by xargs

Tags: linux, bash, grep, clearcase, xargs

Is it possible to grep the result of a command spawned by xargs?

As an example I am trying the following command

```
findbranch prj-xyz -latest|sed 's/^\(.*\/.*\)@@.*$/\1/'|xargs -I {} cleartool lsh {}|grep -m 1 'user'
```

but seems like grep is executing on the entire result set returned by findbranch, rather individual results of lsh

As an example what I want from above is, for every file returned by findbranch and sed combined I would like to find that version which was last modified by a certain user.

**Note** If in case it is of a concern, findbranch is an internal utility.

Answer (score 2):

How about this approach?

```
.... | xargs -I {} bash -c "cleartool lsh {}|grep -m 1 'user'"
```

I guess, this answer is self explanatory for you...

Comment: Yes I see your point. I was just wondering if we could have done without spawning a shell for every input line. But seems like this is the only possible option

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a two phase command? something like

```
findbranch prj-xyz -latest|sed 's/^\(.*\/.*\)@@.*$/\1/' > /tmp/x ; for x in `cat /tmp/x`; do echo $x; done
```

Once you see `$x` is the input you need for `xargs` you can further manipulate it

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel this ought to work:

```
findbranch prj-xyz -latest|sed 's/^\(.*\/.*\)@@.*$/\1/'|parallel cleartool lsh {}'|'grep -m 1 'user'
```

It will still spawn multiple shells, but at least you can use more CPUs to process it.